# memoized matrix chain multiplication in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication, memoization

I feel like I'm really close with this implementation of a memoized matrix chain algorithm in Java, but I'm getting an array out of bounds error on line 45 and 53. These, for some reason, really seem to mess me up. Maybe there's something I'm continually messing up with, but I dunno, obviously. Can anyone help me out?

```
public class Lab2 {
//fields
static int p[];
static int m[][];
final static int INFINITY = 999999999;

public Lab2() {
    // 
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Lab2 lab2 = new Lab2();

Lab2.m = new int[7][7];

Lab2.p = new int[7];
Lab2.p[0] = 20;
Lab2.p[1] = 8;
Lab2.p[2] = 4;
Lab2.p[3] = 25;
Lab2.p[4] = 30;
Lab2.p[5] = 5;
Lab2.p[6] = 10;


int n = Lab2.p.length-1;

//initialize m array to infinity
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for (int j = i; j <= n; j++){
        Lab2.m[i][j]= INFINITY;
    }
}
lab2.lookUpChain(m, p, 1, n);

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
        System.out.println(m[i][j]);
    }
}

}
//
public int lookUpChain(int m[][], int p[], int i, int j ){
if (m[i][j]<INFINITY){
    return m[i][j];
}
if (i == j){
    m[i][j] = 0;
}
else{
    for (int k = i; k <= j; i++){
        int q = (lookUpChain(m,p,i,k)) + (lookUpChain(m,p,k+1,j)) +     (p[i]*p[k]*p[j]);
        if (q < m[i][j]){
            m[i][j] = q;
        }
    }
}
return m[i][j];

}
}
```

Comment: For starters, why are you looping to i and j to 8 (indices 0 - 7) when your array is only 7 x 7 (valid indices 0 - 6)?

Comment: I was just changing things to see if it would fix it. I must have left it at that. I fixed it though. Its in my lookUpChain method, the else box, for loop, it should increment k, not i.

Answer (score 0):

> else{
>       for (int k = i; k <= j; i++)

Change to:

```
else{
for (int k = i; k <= j; k++) // change i to k
```